# Can't seem to understand this last remaining error in c program

Tags: c

The error i don't understand how to fix and need help with is:

> in line 20 and column 28
>
> [Error] cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'void
> lotto(int*, int, int, int, int, int)'

**In this part of the code:**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int read1();
    int even1();
    int even2();
    int sum1();
    int sum2();
    void lotto(int*, int, int, int, int, int);
    int* table_num(int);
    
    int main()
    {
        int a=read1();
        int* t = table_num(a);
        int x=even1();
        int y=even2();
        int g=sum1();
        int h=sum2();
        lotto(&t, a, x, y, g, h); /*error here*/
        return 0;
    }
```

**And here is the function:**

```
void lotto(int* a, int n, int armax, int armin, int atmax, int atmin)
{
    int q, w, z=1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-5; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n-4 ; ++j) 
        {
            for (int k = j+1; k < n-3 ; ++k) 
            {
                for (int l = k+1; l < n-2 ; ++l) 
                {
                    for (int m = l+1; m < n-1 ; ++m) 
                    {
                        for (int i1 = m+1; i1 < n; ++i1) 
                        {

                            q=0;

                            (i%2==0)?q+=1:2;
                            (j%2==0)?q+=1:2;
                            (k%2==0)?q+=1:2;
                            (l%2==0)?q+=1:2;
                            (m%2==0)?q+=1:2;
                            (i1%2==0)?q+=1:2;

                            w=i+j+k+l+m+i1;

                            if((q<=armax||q>=armin)&&(w>=atmin||w<=atmax))
                            {

                                printf("The %d st/nd/rd/th group of 6 numbers is :\t",z);
                                printf("%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d \n\n",*(a+i), *(a+j), *(a+k), *(a+l), *(a+m), (a+i1));
                                z++;

                            }else
                                continue;



                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
    
}
```

if you want the whole code is needed to answer my question i can edit it in

Comment: address of a pointer variable is double pointer - meaning `**`.

Comment: replace this  lotto(&t, a, x, y, g, h); to  lotto(t, a, x, y, g, h);

Answer (score 1):

replace this `lotto(&t, a, x, y, g, h);` to `lotto(t, a, x, y, g, h);`

In the function declaration, you have mentioned the input parameter as **pointer to int**, but again you are passing **pointer to pointer to int** and that is causing error.

Comment: that makes it work BUT now it doesnt show the numbers i want (groups of 6 numbers that i gave), it  shows random numbers (memory locations since i removed the &)

Comment: then check your code. may be you are accessing the value of the location that doesn't have anything or initialize.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is '&t' in your lotto() you're specifying 'int*' and sending an 'int**'. Try compiling without the '&'

Comment: that makes it work BUT now it doesnt show the numbers i want (groups of 6 numbers that i gave), it  shows random numbers (memory locations since i removed the &)